# How to replace Contains() with IndexOf()

Tags: c#, search, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using the following line of code to match search word in my data list. But Contains is case-sensitive if I search for "search" it doesn't match with "Search" or "seArch". 
What are my alternatives to Contains? How Can I replace it with IndexOf?

```
IEnumerable<Compound> allCompounds = _context.Compounds.ToList();
IEnumerable<Compound> filteredCompounds;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
{
    filteredCompounds = allCompounds
             .Where(c => c.CompoundName.Contains(param.sSearch)
                         ||
                         c.RI.Contains(param.sSearch)
                          ||
                         c.MolecularWeight.Contains(param.sSearch)
                         ||
                         c.MolecularFormula.Contains(param.sSearch)
                         );
}
```

Comment: See [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=netframework-4.7.2) for an example of a `Contains()` extension method that allows you to ignore case. (Scroll down to the *Remarks* section.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you solve the problem.

```
        IEnumerable<Compound> allCompounds = _context.Compounds.ToList();
        IEnumerable<Compound> filteredCompounds;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
        {
            filteredCompounds = allCompounds
                     .Where(c => c.CompoundName.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                 ||
                                 c.RI.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                  ||
                                 c.MolecularWeight.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                 ||
                                 c.MolecularFormula.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower())
                                 );
        }
```

Comment: That will slow down the whole process. param.aSearch=param.sShearch.ToLower();onnce will keep code more simple.

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `param.sSearch.ToLower()` replace it every where you have used the `param.sSearch`.. it will work